# python division outputs value 0.0000000002 away from correct value

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, division

I was messing around in my interpreter and found python incorrectly dividing.

```py
>>> a = 24842918
>>> a/2
12421459.0
>>> a/6
4140486.3333333335
```

(`a/6` should be 4140486.333333333**3**)

Why is python returning an output that is incorrect and super close to the correct output?

Comment: Floating point numbers are not infinitely precise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: floats are hard